# Simple Instance Interaction as an eventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

So I have two instances (which are both symbols) one named: `mChar` and one named `b1`
When the two touch I would like to be taken to another frame.

I have tried setting it that if the absolute value of their two x coordinates and y coordinates is less than or equal to *a number*, but that only works if their circles. Is there a way to add an `evenListener` to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe hitTestObject the two symbols? Something like

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, transition);
function transition(e:Event)
{
  if (mChar.hitTestObject(b1))
  {
    gotoAndStop("new frame")
  }
}
```

with new frame being the label of the new frame. that's how I did a frame transition in my current project :) Hope it helps!